# jQuery AJAX request: There was no endpoint listening at

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, json

I am using jQuery to retrieve a JSON package to update my display.  I am attempting to use global ajax handlers to put in a global "AJAX failed" handler.  Unfortunately though when I stop my back end (ASP.NET) the request doesnt "fail" as such, it sends back

```
{"Success":false,"Message":"There was no endpoint listening at
http://localhost:8733/ that could accept the message. This is often
caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if
present, for more details."}
```

Because this doesnt trigger the jQuery ajax error function my global handler doesnt pick it up.  What is happening and how can I force this to cause a proper error?

Here is the stub for my global error handler

```
$(document).ajaxError(function (event, jqxhr, settings, exception) {
    // Increase our error array
    if (++ajaxURLArray[settings.url] >= ajaxMaxFailsBeforeMessage) {
        console.log("Show AJAX error message");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Because this doesnt trigger the jQuery ajax error function my global
>   handler doesnt pick it up. What is happening and how can I force this
>   to cause a proper error?

The error function will be triggered only if the server sends a non-success status code (outside the range 200-299). And when you give it a thought it actually makes sense. That's exactly the purpose of the status code in the HTTP protocol -> to indicate the status of the operation.

So if you want your error handler to trigger, go modify your server side script so that it respects the HTTP protocol a little better and returns for example 400 Bad Request status code along with this error JSON response. I have always wondered how many websites out there are returning *errors* as JSON and setting the status code to 200.

So as you can see if you respect the HTTP protocol you will also reduce the bandwidth consumption of your webssite -> the `"Success"` boolean property of the JSON you have shown becomes kind of useless. That's the role of the HTTP status code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I was catching the internal exception then returning a JSON message. I suppose I didnt think it would still work after stopping the debugger which confused me at first. Thanks.  The original reason behind this was the thinking I could get more error info back if it failed, how can I get the exception info from the failed AJAX request (it now sends 500)?